# Error 503 Maximum threads for service reached

Tags: support

I'm getting the following error on certain tabs when refreshing the page:

[image]

It only happens on certain tabs, not all of them.

**Update #1**

The site is running extremely slow with a new error when interacting with site features:

[image]

**Update #2**

**Country:** England

Comment: Same thing here, even the adds don't work

Comment: Might help if you share roughly your location. Looks like a Fastly error, the CDN provider SE uses.

Comment: @rene updated with my country.

Comment: Hmm, I can't repro and I'm just across the North Sea ...

Comment: Yes, the CDN is the [likely culprit](https://www.fastly.com/blog/benefits-using-varnish).  SO does not use Varnish, they like Redis.

Comment: Fastly itself thinks all is fine: https://status.fastly.com/

Comment: Strange, because Varnish's error pages usually show Fastly's branding on them (though, it's rare to see one). That could mean this is an issue so unanticipated that nobody realized it was still the stock page :) Pinged our SREs about it, though I'm not 100% certain it's Fastly's use of Varnish. Could be ISP using it as a caching proxy (similar to squid).

Comment: @TimPost Sorry for delay, i was away. It was  Fastly hiccup ,  fastly.com was unavailable for a short period, at least for me....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were some issues with Fastly that caused the problem. It resolved itself after a bit and should be back to normal.

Comment: Out of curiosity is there a "status" tag for these sort of issues?

Comment: @Script47 Not really for support issues. If it was a bug that was fixed, then we'd use a status tag.